# Python How to convert a float as hex to decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I've read in some data from a csv file with pandas. The data is incomplete and therefore contains many nan values.
I want to add a column to the data which converts the hex values to decimal values. Unfortunately, the column with the hex values are all read as floats, not strings because they just happen to have those values.
Example data

```
   val
0 20.0
1  nan
2 20.0
```

The simple way to convert a hex to decimal in python seems to be:`int('20.0',16)`, which should yield `32`.

However, since this is pandas I cannot convert the values to int, or at least I keep getting an error stating that.
My current code is:

```
df['valdec'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['val']), 
                    df['val'], 
                    int(df['val'].astype(int).astype(str), 16))
```

This fails with the error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

without the `astype(int)` the value is `"20.0"` which cannot be converted.
Is there another way to interpret a float value as a hex value and convert to decimal when working with pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask the rows of interest and double cast and call `apply`:

```
In [126]:
df['valdec'] = df['val'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
df

Out[126]:
    val  valdec
0  20.0    32.0
1   NaN     NaN
2  20.0    32.0
```

So firstly we call `dropna` to remove the `NaN`, this allows us to cast to `int` using `.astype(int)` then convert to `str` by calling `.astype(str)`.

We then call `apply` on this to convert to hex and assign the result of all this to the new column

Note that the `dtype` of the new column will be `float` as the presence of `NaN` enforces this, you won't be able to have a mixture of `int`s and `float`s

As pointed out by @jasonharper, casting to `int` here will lose any fractional 
part so a higher precision method would be to use `float.fromhex`:

```
In [128]:
df['valdec'] = df['val'].astype(str).dropna().apply(lambda x: float.fromhex(x))
df

Out[128]:
    val  valdec
0  20.0    32.0
1   NaN     NaN
2  20.0    32.0
```

Comment: Conversion by way of `int` will lose any fractional part of the numbers, of course.  The proper conversion from a hexadecimal float string is `float.fromhex(s)`.

Comment: @jasonharper have added your suggestion

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. I had found the dropna, but forgot how python handles the dropped values. Great solution!